# Script not running! Also how to attach timestamp in mail?

Tags: shell-script, cron, mail-command

I have the following bash script...

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Delete JUNK temp folder 

if [ -d JUNK/FOLDER/PATH ] 
then 
rm -rf JUNK/FOLDER/PATH 
echo "Cleansed JUNK directory successfully!" 
/usr/bin/mail -s "JUNK folder deleted successfully" example@gmail.com <<< "Success!" 
else 
/usr/bin/mail -s "JUNK folder not found" example@gmail.com <<< "Success!" 
fi
```

I have it in my crontab as below

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home1/ramnath/public_html/myscripts/deltemp.sh
```

Q1: Why is the script is not running? Is there an error? When I manually run the script in the terminal, I get an error:

`bash myscripts/deltemp.sh
Cleansed JUNK directory successfully!
myscripts/deltemp.sh: line 8: mail: command not found`

=====================

NOTE: The issue is fixed. I just used
`mailx -s "JUNK directory deleted" "example@gmail.com"`

Comment: The `mail` command is not found in your current `PATH`. Either specify the absolure filename like `/bin/mail` or change the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to give absolute paths in your script, `cron` might run your script somewhere else, not in your `$HOME`.

You probably haven't got the venerable `mail(1)` program installed. And if you have, for sanity's sake, also give full paths to any executables your script runs.

In general, for *any* script that runs with extra privileges (as another user, started automatically) it is a little extra work to use absolute paths, set `PATH` explicitly, or run executables by full path. That way you protect against running in some strange directory, or picking up the wrong (even malicious) executable, and save much grief.

Comment: I have provided the complete path in my script. Is that what you meant?

Comment: `JUNK/MAIL/FOLDER` is not a "complete path", far from it.

Comment: In my server I have specified the path as `/home1/ramnath/public_html/../junk/folder/` Since this a public forum I am abstaining from disclosing the actual path.

Comment: @Ramnathm, then use a fake path like `/home/joesixpack/here/is/junk`

Comment: SOLVED. The only error that I fixed was use `mailx` instead.

`mailx -s "JUNK directory deleted" "example@gmail.com"`

Comment: But I am not sure why someone awarded a negative point to the question?! :-(

Answer (score 1):

1) The error pretty much speaks for itself: your script cannot find the `mail` binary. Either it isn't installed, or it is but isn't in your $PATH and therefore you have to call it specifying the full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/mail`).

2) You do not need to attach a timestamp manually to the payload passed to `mail`, as e-mail messages bear already a timestamp in the `Date:` header:

```
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 06:30:10 -0800
```

Just ensure that the sending server is time-synchronized (e.g. via NTP) and you'll be fine.

Comment: `mailx -s "JUNK directory deleted" "example@gmail.com"` solved the issue. Not sure why my question was awarded -1 by someone?!